# ‘A person should operate a machine three times’

Tags: meaning, frequency

Person A should operate machine A in the morning.

Person B should operate machine B in the afternoon.

Person C should operate machine C at night.

They shouldn’t operate a machine together.

Somebody says ‘a person should operate a machine three times’ (which is meant to mean a person should operate a machine each time of the three times) is wrong because it only means ‘the same person should operate the same machine three times.’ Is it true that it **only** means ‘the same person should operate the same machine three times’? Can ‘a person should operate a machine three times’ also mean ‘a person should operate three machines’ at least?

Comment: This question is similar to [your other one on ELU](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/579466/two-people-have-a-baby-interpretation), and I would have the same advice here. You've illustrated a fairly complex situation, then tried to sum it up in a very short sentence. If you don't include the context, then such a short sentence can't have "only" one meaning.

Answer (score 1):

I would say that, yes, "a person" doing something "three times" is quite clear in meaning that the same one person does the action three times.  To convey what you truly mean in the clearest way possible, it might require multiple sentences.

My best one-sentence alternative, however, would be: "Three people should take turns operating their machines."

This clearly discusses three separate people operating their own machines on a rotating basis, and "taking turns" means that they should not operate at the same time.

Comment: Can ‘a person should operate a machine three times’ mean ‘a person should operate three machines’ at least?

Comment: I would say no.  "A machine" only talks about one, so it would be a stretch to say it is about multiple machines.

Comment: @user284747 And I would say yes, it can, but it needs the help of context to say it. "A person should drive a car three times in their life" —there's no assumption that it's the same car. But I added context. You can't just create extremely short, spare sentences and then insist that they can't possibly mean a certain thing. In both this question and the one on ELL, they mean next to *nothing* with no further context.

Comment: myacorn, thanks for giving an answer! Be sure to read carefully, though. The OP never used the phrase "one person" (would have been helpful if they had), only "a person." Also, in the contrived scenario, there are three machines.

Comment: Thanks, Andy!  I've adjusted the answer slightly to account for these oversights (a person instead of one person, and their machines instead of the machine).